# 'Resultset cannot be resolved to a type'

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, jdbc, resultset

I used one resultset variable for one query, which worked fine. But when I try to declare more Resultset variables for other queries in the same .jsp page, I get 'Resultset not resolved type' error for them.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [53] in the jsp file: [/frozen.jsp]
Resultset cannot be resolved to a type
50: }
51: avg=avg/n;
52: 
53: Resultset rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("select amarate from amarating where movie_id='frozen'");
54: Resultset rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery("select dor,length,genre from moviedetails where movie_id='frozen'");
55: String ama = rs2.getString("amarate");
56: String dor = rs3.getString("dor");


An error occurred at line: [54] in the jsp file: [/frozen.jsp]
Resultset cannot be resolved to a type
51: avg=avg/n;
52: 
53: Resultset rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("select amarate from amarating where movie_id='frozen'");
54: Resultset rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery("select dor,length,genre from moviedetails where movie_id='frozen'");
55: String ama = rs2.getString("amarate");
56: String dor = rs3.getString("dor");
57: String len = rs3.getString("length");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:212)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:601)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: I assume, stmt3 is correctly created. So all looks fine. Could it be, that 'length' is a reserved word from your database and you need to put it into quotation marks?

Comment: It looks like your JSP doesn't import `java.sql.ResultSet`, but without your code we can't be for sure. But seriously: this type of code doesn't belong in a JSP.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but it does execute one of the three resultset variables which is odd. 

I am learning. Jsp, mysql and html are the languages I'm aware of for building a website.

Comment: `ResultSet` has a capital `S` at the start of `Set`.  I'm guessing your first result-set works because it correctly capitalises the `S`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Good point, I had entirely missed that misspelling

Comment: As Luke indicates you have a type: `Resultset` vs `ResultSet`, and although JSPs can be used to build websites, it is considered outdated technology, but even if you do use it, data access code really should not be part of your JSP, but factored out to separate classes that can be better tested in isolation. Don't mixup presentation logic with business logic and data retrieval.